# Styled usernames in messages with NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I am a bit confused how I can add attributed components to text when I do not know upfront where the add the keys to. I am building a  chat app and I am using `UITextView` to display messages between users.

I want to support tagging users. So when a user mentions another user in a message, I want to make the username of the tagged person bold. The problem is that:

- The text which users are dynamic
- The usernames are dynamic (ofcourse)

I don't understand how I can make this work because I need to provide `NSRange`s to `NSAttributedString`. I don't know how I can find them. What I *can* do, which might help, is add metadata in the original `String` to find out where usernames are. So I can operate on this string:

```
Hi @%Jhon Doe%@, do you like to speak to @%The Manager%@
```

And this must be transformed to (just an example with bold italic traits) attributed text on `UITextView`:

Hi ***Jhon Doe***, do you like to speak to ***The Manager***

Please note that the @% prefix and suffix are just something out of my head, it can be anything.

I am wondering now how I can make this work. Using Regex to find usernames? But how will I get the `NSRange` from it? Find methods on `String`?

I am having a hard time converting a `Range` to `NSRange`. I am also confused with UTF-16 the `NSRange` uses. I am just using UTF-8. Since I am having so much trouble, I was wondering if there is an easy way.

I asked a similar question the other day, but that was just attributed text at the start/ending of another `String`: [Adding attribute to markdown NSAttributedString goes out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72056148/adding-attribute-to-markdown-nsattributedstring-goes-out-of-bounds). This question is specific about attributed text **somewhere, not predefined** in a `String`.

Comment: I can't quite understand what does "The text which users are dynamic" mean, could you please explain and provide examples?

Comment: Since I've already answered similar question, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71525773/change-word-colour-from-sentence-with-regex/71526873#71526873 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124406/make-patterns-to-use-nsregularexpression/54127239#54127239 You could adapt them. The `NSRange` are inside hte `NSTextCheckResult`, and you need to iterate by "reverse" order (to avoid range issues).

Comment: @Larme Thanks, I think I got it working with one of the solutions you mentioned :) I upvoted it!

Comment: If you still have issue, do no hesitate to edit your question with current code (which I guess is adapted from mine), and we might help to debug ;)